# "Put On Hold As Unclear What You're Asking" How Can I Help Get This Question Unheld?

Tags: discussion, support

So yesterday I stumbled upon a question on Askubuntu; [MATE menu is missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483358/mate-menu-is-missing). It's a troubleshooting question about Mate Desktop and while not ideally worded I found it easy enough to understand what the OP is talking about especially after looking at the screenshot. The OP installed Mate, but upon logging in only receives the desktop icons. I would personally love to see what the answer is to this question, but unfortunately it has been put on hold as unclear.

> put on hold as unclear what you're asking by Censored, Censored, Censored, Censored♦ 14 hours ago
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question or leave a comment.

What can I do to help the OP get his/her question unheld? I can't think of any additional details to request be edited in, and I don't have an answer to give. Even if I did have an answer I wouldn't be able to give it, because the question is on hold.

Comment: Question looks fine to me, I'd just clarify it a bit "How can I get the panels, like the ones shown in this picture [insert picture of default mate desktop". If you can do that, I'll reopen it :)

Comment: @Seth I edited the question. It now has a screenshot depicting the result the OP is trying to get.